# How monitor TEMP space allocation for a particular object type like Clob\Blob

Tags: oracle, java, jdbc

I am new to Oracle and i wanted to know if there is a way to monitor Clob\Blob objects allocation in Oracle Temp Space.

With JDBC 4.0, we have clob.free() and blob.free() methods and i want a way to verify the benefits using these methods in my application.

Does anyone know how can i do that and/or possibly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting to an Oracle instance 11.2+, you can fetch data from the column temp_space_allocated of the view v$active_session_history, which shows the amount of TEMP memory (in bytes) consumed by your session at the time the sample was taken.

Otherwise, you may look at the V$TEMPSEG_USAGE view, column blocks, and convert it to megabytes depending on your tbs block size.